# varA = varA + varB doesn't work in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm making a running total calculator method for my angular project in ts,

```
Total(){
let t: any;
for (let n = 0; n < this.checkoutItems.length; n++) {
  let key = this.checkoutItems[n].item_id ;
  this.itemsService.getCheckoutItem(key, 2).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.checkoutItem = response;
  let y = localStorage.getItem(key);
  console.log("y:");
  console.log(y);
  let x=+y;
  console.log("x:");
  console.log(x);
  let a= +this.checkoutItems[n].price;
  console.log("a:");
  console.log(a);
  let b = a*x;
  console.log("b:");
  console.log(b);
   t +=b;
  console.log("t:");
  console.log(t);
  })
}
}
```

Everything works fine upto the console log of b, they print the desired output on my console but for some reason the console log of t returns NaN ? why does that happen? I'm sorry I'm new to typescript.

Comment: I am confused. What does this have to do with [tag:local-storage]? What does this have to do with [tag:angular]? Also, what's the point of using TypeScript if you type everything as [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), which essentially means "no type checking, just as in ECMAScript"? Why not just use ECMAScript, then? Please, make sure to construct a [mre]. Your problem can be demonstrated in two lines of code, whereas the way it is written now, it requires me to install Angular, create a project, create a service and a couple of other things to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write like this . You can't add anything to any if you haven't initialize it. So check firstly if undefined or not then use it

```
t ? t+=b : t=b;
```

Comment: my bad, I thought any takes the type the object parsed into it. It works when you define it to 0 initially. thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

`t +=b` means `t = t+b` so where did set `t` before this line?

Because of that... you have `t = undefined + b` so NaN, that is what I guess without trying your code (shame on me).

If you are dealing with a counter you can safely set `t` to 0 when you define it at the very beginning. Something like => `let t = 0`.
If `t` is your result you can even use reduce avoiding an external variable declaration and a for loop.

Comment: my bad, I thought variable type any takes the type the object parsed into it , this is all new to me have a lot to learn XD

Comment: Don't worry, it's normal. I would suggest you to use different approaches. A good approach is using `const` everywhere and when you can't use it ask yourself if you are implementing it in the right way. 99% of the time you don't need `let`. You simply have to think at how implement something leaving its immutability.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can really be [demonstrated in just two lines](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&esModuleInterop=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=99#code/DYUwLgBGBcEIYDsCeBuAUAYwPYIM5dADpgsBzACkgGoIAWAJgEoUg):

```js
let t: any;
t + 42
//=> NaN
```

The reason you get [`NaN`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-nan) is that [uninitialized variables evaluate to `undefined`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and [`undefined` is converted to `NaN` in a numeric context](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-11) and [`NaN + anything` is `NaN`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-add).

The reason why TypeScript was not able to help you and point out your mistake is that by explicitly typing `t` as [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), you have essentially told TypeScript: "I have no idea what this is, you have no idea what this is, so let's just pretend everything is fine, okay?" In other words, you have told TypeScript to not help you.

If you had typed it as a [`number`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#number), for example, [this would have happened](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&esModuleInterop=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=99#code/DYUwLgBGBcEHYFcC2AjEAnA3AKAMYHs4BnfUAOmHwHMAKSAaggBYAmASkyA):

```js
let t: number;
t + 42
// ERROR: Variable 't' is used before being assigned.
```

[The correct way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&esModuleInterop=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=99#code/DYUwLgBJC8EAwG4BQBjA9gOwM5tAOmDQHMAKSAaggBYAmASgSA) would be to initialize `t` to the identity value of the operation you are performing. (For addition, the identity is `0`.)

```js
let t: number = 0; // Or just `let t = 0` and the type will be inferred correctly
t + 42
//=> 42
```

The *really* correct solution solution would probably be some form of a [`reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) over `this.checkoutItems`.